# Load local Electron files as secure content

Tags: node.js, electron, protocols, content-security-policy

Electron loads local resources by default via the `file:///` protocol, which, of course, has its own limitations. Serving under the `file:///` protocol will disable you from sending AJAX requests to files also locally stored and will also block Browser APIs like `navigator.getUserMedia()`, throwing a "Permission denied" error. The latter bothering me the most, I was unable to find any way around it. Is it possible to somehow *cheat* the browser the content is served over the `https` protocol? Could I run a `localhost` server via electron?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: electron itself runs on a node server

Comment: @Aditya_Anand so I could my files using `localhost/dir/dir/file.js`? And what is the root?

Comment: You can access the files with
mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + "/build/index.html");

Comment: maybe you want to refer to my answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618828/load-local-json-into-electron-cant-use-require-include/61621322#61621322